# TensorCPU build: dependencies downloading issue

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow cpu version on my centos 6.5, but i am stuck :-

```
bazel build -c opt  //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
........
WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more information. You can turn off this warning via --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.
INFO: Downloading from http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz: 0B
```

it tries to download jpeg/eigen/png tar files but is unable to do so due to lack of internet connectivity on my machine .
I can download & put all these dependencies somewhere within the tensorflow sourcecode directory so that build procedure automatically detect them.

Could you please suggest the path to that directory ( relative to tensorflow src root directory)? or is there a file which needs modification?

I tried placing it under $TENSOR_SRC_ROOT/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/external, but that did not help.

Eagerly awaiting your replies,

Comment: http://bazel.io/docs/be/workspace.html#local_repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to bazel development team, setting HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY in my environment resolved the issue.